# Add Session using Javascript in MVC 4 Razor

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm writing application which upload file, first I need some configuration for file storage 
i read the first Ten rows and show them to user, user provide configuration and I'll upload the file .

i tried this

```
<script>
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
function readSingleFile(evt) {
    var FileBlock = "";   
    var contents="";
    var f = evt.target.files[0];
    if (f) {
        var r = new FileReader();
        r.onload = function (e) {
            contents = e.target.result;
            var Rows = contents.toString().split("\n", 10);
            FileBlock = Rows[0];
             for (var i = 1 ; i < Rows.length; i++) {
                 FileBlock += "|" + Rows[i];
             }
             alert(contents);

            @{
                Session["Test"] = @:contents+"";
             }

            OpenDockPanelBySumbitForm("ImporterPanel", "form",FileBlock);
            Hide_ContentZone_Panel();
        }
        r.readAsText(f);      
    } else {
        alert("Failed to load file");
    }
}
```

this piece of code not work

```
@{
   Session["Test"] = @:contents+"";
 }
```

if anyone Can Help I'll be grateful, Thanks in participation.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to set a client-side value to a server-side object, which makes no sense.

Comment: it is more complicated than you think 
javascript prevent getting file Path and I don't want to upload the file unless i get the user configuration, so i need having access to the file content, One way store the file in session or cookie 
problem in cookie user may disable cookie so the website will not be able to finish this task.

if you have an idea about getting access to file content this will be great.

Thanks for your Interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is no way to do that, because C# Code compiled first before Javascript, so C# will not be able to see Javascript code while the opposite is possible.

one way to solve is move your script to another folder -plugins - to insure that it will compile first.

[check Source here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/48874/accessing-javascript-variable-from-c-and-vice-vers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net code is running server-based dynamic work in Javascript.
JavaScript assign values ​​to variables based on the server can not. However, keeping in hidden variables you can use;

http://i.hizliresim.com/aq336d.png

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnsession" name="sessionData" value=" @ViewBag.session??"" " />
public ActionResult test(string sessionData){
Session["Test"] = sessionData;
ViewBag.session = Session["Test"];
return View();
}
```